# In Ubuntu 20.04, can I format an unallocated partition of an NTFS hard drive as ext4 without corrupting my drive?

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, format, ext4

I have a 2 TB hard drive currently where the majority of space is an NTFS partition. I have around 168 GB of unallocated free space. Is it possible for me to use `gparted` and to just add on an `ext4` partition? Would this potentially destroy anything? If this works, would I choose `primary`, `logical`, or `extended`?

[image]

**Add-on:**

`Gparted` asks for these options:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're safe to make partitions in unallocated space.

It looks like the hard drive is using GUID Partition Tables (GPT) which no longer uses the primary/extended/logical partition scheme.  Is something prompting you for that choice or are you just doing research ahead of time?

Comment: thanks for the response. Gparted is asking for it, and I have attached a screenshot of it above. Would you have any idea what the appropriate selection would be?

Comment: my apologies, the logical and extended portions are greyed out. is it correct to format as primary?

Comment: Yep, GPT only has primary partition types so you're fine to choose primary.

Comment: thanks, if you don't mind me asking one more thing -- would keeping 0 space preceding and 0 after be ok? I see some drives (like my main drive) force a 1 megabyte free space partition at the end.

Comment: Leaving 0 before and following should be fine.  Some hard drives require weird spacing (maybe drive geometry?) and gparted, assuming you're using a semi-recent version, should handle it.  Don't be concerned if gparted ends up tweaking the numbers slightly even if you put 0 for before+following.

Comment: thank you! this worked!